# Was this repetition of the number 333 done on purpose?

Tags: discussion

I like to go on various SE sites and read the most popular questions during my downtime at work. I was reading [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2937/story-where-the-number-3-is-the-monster) about a story with 3:33 being on the clock, a question which intrigued me because one of my best friends has a superstition about that exact number (he was born at 3:33am). I then read the fantastic answer, and couldn't help but notice that it had.... **333** votes. Is this intentional?

[image: 333]

Comment: 334 now. Move along... :P

Comment: I thought I remembered a discussion about this (meta? chat? now-deleted comments?) but can't find it. Maybe I'm just remembering when the question had 33 upvotes (https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/198?m=3202787#3202787)

Comment: Maybe the title could be made a *little* less click-baity.

Comment: I wouldn't call it click baity at all, but whatever. Ambiguous at best, maybe. Change the title if you want, I just thought it was cool so I posted it here for yall to enjoy.

Comment: Oh no, we're caught in a temporal loop and Data is trying to [send the number 3 as a message](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cause_and_Effect_(Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation))!

Comment: I just can't believe this...

Comment: We had a similar answer about 7 being the most magical number (from Harry Potter). It got 7 votes, partly because the community thought it was a funny thing to see (it also happened to be a good answer)

Comment: We also had questions about Douglas Adams that gathered 42 votes at one time. These coincidences happen. Sure, it's rather a big coincidence that there are currently 42 of those, but still.

Answer (score 20):

There is no way that could be intentional, because there is no way to control other people's votes. There *is* one way, an it is called a moderator lock. However, according to the [timeline](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/105743/timeline) of the answer, a lock never happened. Same timeline also indicates that the answer last received an upvote on June 13th, which was the vote that brought it up to 333. I'm assuming now that you've posted this question, it'll receive some more votes, and the delicate balance will be broken. But kudos to you for noticing it ;)

Comment: Nice one, I didn't know you could check for that stuff! I can't wait to show this to my friend; he absolutely fears the time 3:33. He was born at that time in the morning, and (sadly) his mother died at 3:33 in March a few years ago. He also recurringly wakes up at night and sees his clock at 3:33.

Comment: It's not locked. - I went to upvote it and it flicked up to 334 and then changed my mind and unvoted in order to keep in on 333 - it seemed appropriate condsidering the question but not the when considering the answer.

Comment: _Now_ we have to bring it up to 555 to be consistent with the answer.

Comment: After it reaches 555 votes, we'd have to flag mods to lock the question..